# AWS EventBridge: Add multiple event details to a target parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, aws-event-bridge

I created an EventBridge rule that triggers a Sagemaker Pipeline when someone uploads a new file to an S3 bucket. As new input files become available, they will be uploaded to the bucket for processing. I'd like the pipeline to process only the uploaded file, and so thought to pass in the S3 URL of the file as a parameter to the Pipeline. Since the full URL doesn't exist as a single field value in the S3 event, I was wondering if there is some way to concatenate multiple field values into a single parameter value that EventBridge will pass on to the target.

For example, I know the name of the uploaded file can be sent from EventBridge using `$.detail.object.key` and the bucket name can be sent using `$.detail.bucket.name`, so I'm wondering if I can send both somehow to get something like this to the Sagemaker Pipeline `s3://my-bucket/path/to/file.csv`

For what it's worth, I tried splitting the parameter into two (one being `s3://bucket-name/` and the other being `default_file.csv`) when defining the pipeline, but got an error saying `Pipeline variables do not support concatenation` when combining the two into one.

The relevant pipeline step is

`step_transform = TransformStep(name = "Name", transformer=transformer,inputs=TransformInput(data=variable_of_s3_path)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Input transformers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-transform-target-input.html) manipulate the event payload that EventBridge sends to the target.  Transforms consist of (1) an "input path" that maps substitution variable names to JSON-paths in the event and (2) a "template" that references the substitution variables.

Input path:

```json
{
  "detail-bucket-name": "$.detail.bucket.name",
  "detail-object-key": "$.detail.object.key"
}
```

Input template that concatenates the s3 url and outputs it along with the original event payload:

```json
{
  "s3Url": "s3://<detail-bucket-name>/<detail-object-key>",
  "original": "$"
}
```

Define the transform in the EventBridge console by editing the rule: `Rule > Select Targets > Additional Settings`.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm missing a step somewhere - my Sagemaker Pipeline parameter is called BatchData. Does this mean I should replace s3Url in your code with BatchData? Should I also add a parameter name and value in the "Sagemaker Pipeline parameters" section? If so, what should the value there be?

Comment: understsood. The transform itself should send the variable s3Url out of EventBridge to the target, right? It does not seem to be making it onwards in my case.

Comment: @user1114 Right. After some Googling, I believe your first comment is right. You must go back to the [EventBridge target](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-targets.html#targets-specific-parms) and [add parameters to pass to your pipeline execution using a name and value pair.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/pipeline-eventbridge.html#pipeline-eventbridge-schedule-console).  The key is your parameter name, `BatchData`.  The value is `$.s3Url`, the JSON-path in the transformed event.

Comment: Thanks @fedonev. When I added the parameter ("BatchData":"$s3Url"} to the rule it stopped firing unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, the typo is only on the comment. I tried it with the dot "$.s3Url" in AWS

Comment: I'm doing it in the EventBridge GUI on the aws management console - there's a "Name" text field and a "Value" text field for each parameter. The GUI also has a message saying "SageMaker Pipeline parameters are used to execute a SageMaker pipeline. Parameter names are static while parameter values canbe either a static value or a dynamic JSON pth to the event payload"

Comment: @user1114  Question: Sagemaker gets triggered OK BEFORE the parameter name-value was set in EB, but not AFTER?  Debug tip: what if you hardcode a url value (instead of the JSON-path)?

Comment: Good catch - it wasn't triggering because apparently the parameter name has to be defined in the pipeline.

Comment: @user1114.  I created my sagemaker pipeline and parameters by following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/build-and-manage-parameters.html. But I still cant trigger eventbridge. It triggers without the parameters. Any clue on what I could be missing ?

Comment: @Yash Did you set the parameter names in both EventBridge and the pipeline definition?