# How to pass matched event AND constant from AWS EventBridge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I want to invoke a lambda and I want to pass the entire matched event and I want to also pass a constant. I am aware of the input transformer but I don't want to use it because the matched event schema can change.

This is essentially what I am trying to do:

Input path:

```
{
    "originalEvent": "$"
}
```

Input Template:

```
{
    "myConstant": "hey now brown cow"
    "originalEvent": "<originalEvent>"
}
```

So given the following 2 events:

```
event 1
{
   "id": "123",
   "detail": {
     "state": "RUNNING",
     "someProp": "someVal"
   }
}
event 2
{
   "id": "456",
   "detail": {
     "state": "FAILED",
     "someOtherProp": "someOtherValue"
   }
}
```

The expected transformed/generated json that is delivered to the target:

```
transformed json 1
{
    "myConstant": "hey now brown cow",
    "originalEvent": {
       "id": "123",
       "detail": {
         "state": "RUNNING",
         "someProp": "someVal"
       }
    }
}
transformed json 2
{
    "myConstant": "hey now brown cow",
    "originalEvent": {
       "id": "456",
       "detail": {
         "state": "FAILED",
         "someOtherProp": "someOtherVal"
       }
    }
}
```

Instead what is actually happening is this:

```
transformed json 1
{
    "myConstant": "hey now brown cow",
    "originalEvent": "[Object object]"
}
transformed json 2
{
    "myConstant": "hey now brown cow",
    "originalEvent": "[Object object]"
}
```

I've also tried doing it as it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72120382/aws-eventbridge-add-multiple-event-details-to-a-target-parameter) but no dice.

Again - I DO NOT want to re-create the matched json object in the input path/template via `$.whatever`. I'd have to do that for the entire object which I want to avoid because the schema may be unknown to the event rule. I don't want to have to worry about mapping all of the possible existing properties on the incoming event.

Is this not possible?

Comment: Could you please add an example of an input event and an output event you want generated out of it? What you have in your post are examples of transformers.

Comment: @Quassnoi should have included it in original post. Updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input path:

```
{}
```

Template:

```
{
  "originalEvent": <aws.events.event.json>,
  "myConstant": "hey now brown cow"
}
```

Comment: There it is thank you!